# Eager Loading Faulting WCF with Entity Framework 6

Tags: c#, wcf, entity-framework, entity-framework-6

I have a WCF service project that is faulting when I am trying to eager load entities. (.Include).

My setup is like this:

- WCF Service Library Project
- Class Library Project -- Edmx is housed there
- Class Library Project -- View Models housed there
- WPF Project

I have spent some time trying to fix this serialization issue when I am eager loading entities.

Here is where I am now. The below works:

```
[OperationContract]
[FaultContract(typeof(HandleException))]
[ApplyProxyDataContractResolver]
List<Item> GetItems();

    using (var dbContext = new MyEntities())
    {
        dbContext.Configuration.LazyLoadingEnabled = false;
        return dbContext.Items.ToList();
    }
```

And displays this:

[image: Results]

But this faults and gives the generic error message

> Failed to invoke the service. Possible causes: The service is offline or inaccessible; the client-side configuration does not match the proxy; the existing proxy is invalid. Refer to the stack trace for more detail. You can try to recover by starting a new proxy, restoring to default configuration, or refreshing the service.

This is what is throwing the exception

```
return dbContext.Items.Include(x => x.Category).ToList();
```

I have tried changing the return type to `Item` and then something like this

```
return dbContext.Items.Include(x => x.Category).FirstOrDefault(t => t.Category.CategoryId == t.CategoryId);
```

And I have added `[CyclicReferencesAware(true)]` but the test client is still bombing out.

Categories are a self referencing hierarchy -- I think that is why it can't handle it.

How can I resolve this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

WcfTestClient.exe can't handle cyclic references - have you tried testing with your own custom code?

Comment: I just figured it out had to add dbContext.Configuration.ProxyCreationEnabled = false; And then add back the CyclicReference attribute and it worked correctly.